# Bootstrap Bread Crumbs content and stacking

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, breadcrumbs

So I am using bootstrap breadcrumbs for some form page but I cannot get the active tag to be used on the content and the stacking when I make the page smaller doesn't go well because of the classes. Long story short, this is what I want to do [image: First picture]
and this is what I get [image: Second Picture]
So this is the html code.

```
    <!-- BREAD CRUMBS -->
<section class="borrow_breadcrumbs">
  <ol class="breadcrumb text-center">
    <li class="active"><img src="img/star.png"><div class="bc">Credit rating</div></li>
    <li><img class="fix" src="img/img2.png"><div class="bc">Select your loan</div></li>
    <li><img src="img/img3.png"><div class="bc">Confirmation</div></li>
    <li><img src="img/img4.png"><div class="bc">Get your loan</div></li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

And here is the CSS

```
 .borrow_breadcrumbs{
  width:100%;
}

.borrow_breadcrumbs .bc{
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 14px;

}
.borrow_breadcrumbs ol{
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(39, 38, 38, 0.25);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(39, 38, 38, 0.25);
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs li{
  padding:20px 50px;
}

.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  content: "---------"
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > .active {

  background-color: rgba(63, 255, 0, 0.18);
}
```

Ignore the border on both sides, it came during taking the picture. And the img I used are already green so as you can see in the second picture so All i need to do now for testing is make hr line on the right part of active and some how get a line like that and make it stack properly on smaller device.

[Bread CRUMB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cf8p8s13jpyamz2/stack.zip?dl=0) Here is the FILE if you can help me edit it then it would be better.

Comment: This might help : http://plnkr.co/edit/ERxkwejbp8S9fo7G4ptp?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your CSS to the one below.

```
 .borrow_breadcrumbs {
   width: 100%;
 }

 .borrow_breadcrumbs .bc {
   margin-top: 10px;
   color: #666666;
   font-size: 14px;
 }

 .borrow_breadcrumbs ol {
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(39, 38, 38, 0.25);
   border-top: 1px solid rgba(39, 38, 38, 0.25);
   font-size: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }

 .borrow_breadcrumbs li {
   padding: 20px 50px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: rgba(63, 255, 0, 0.18);
   margin-right: 80px; /*Give according to your need*/
   position: relative;
 }

.borrow_breadcrumbs li:last-child{
  margin-right: 0;
}

.borrow_breadcrumbs li:before{
  content: "";
  width: 50px; /*Give according to your need*/
  height: 2px; /*Give according to your need*/
  background:#000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 15px; /*Give according to your need*/
}

.borrow_breadcrumbs li:last-child:before{
  display: none;
}

 .borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > .active {
   background-color: rgba(63, 255, 0, 0.18);
 }
```

Working Codepen Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLxWed

Comment: but the line is not getting highlighted

Comment: .borrow_breadcrumbs li.active:before{
  background-color: rgba(63, 255, 0, 0.18);
}

add this line of css.

Comment: I added the file if you could help me out there it would be better 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cf8p8s13jpyamz2/stack.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using bootstrap grid layout - http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/.
2. Also, if you can get use bootstrap glyphicons - http://getbootstrap.com/components/

It will give you desired result. All the best

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this `:after` or `:before` in css

```css
.borrow_breadcrumbs{
  width:100%;
}

.borrow_breadcrumbs .bc{
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 14px;

}
.borrow_breadcrumbs ol{
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(39, 38, 38, 0.25);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(39, 38, 38, 0.25);
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs li{
  padding:20px 50px;
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li{background-color:gray;float:none;    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 12px;list-style-type:none;position:relative;margin-left:50px;}

.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  right:102%;
  left:-25px;
  top:50%;
  border-top:2px solid green;
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb{font-size:0;white-space:nowrap;}

.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li + li:after, .borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb >  li:first-child:after  {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  left:102%;
  right:-25px;
  top:50%;
  border-top:2px solid green;
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li:last-child:after{
display:none;
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > .active {

  background-color: rgba(63, 255, 0, 0.18);
}
```

```html
<section class="borrow_breadcrumbs">
  <ol class="breadcrumb text-center">
    <li class="active"><img src="img/star.png"><div class="bc">Credit rating</div></li>
    <li><img class="fix" src="img/img2.png"><div class="bc">Select your loan</div></li>
    <li><img src="img/img3.png"><div class="bc">Confirmation</div></li>
    <li><img src="img/img4.png"><div class="bc">Get your loan</div></li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

============================= **Add this code in your css file or this page**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li{float:none;    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 12px;list-style-type:none;position:relative;margin-left:50px;}

.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  right:102%;
  left:-25px;
  top:50%;
  border-top:2px solid green;
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb{font-size:0;white-space:nowrap;}

.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li + li:after, .borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb >  li:first-child:after  {
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  left:102%;
  right:-25px;
  top:50%;
  border-top:2px solid green;
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li:last-child:after{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

and Result is

[image]

Comment: I added the file since your code was adding some problems, can you please check the file I uploaded . 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cf8p8s13jpyamz2/stack.zip?dl=0

Comment: And the stack is a big problem since it does not stack properly with the lines.

Comment: @MasnadNihit Hi i have check to this file please add this code in your css file or this page as like to anwer

Comment: I added the last codes you sent, but there is no active tab and the line on the right is not active as well..

Comment: @MasnadNihit for active demo is try to this code -->  .borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li.acitve + li:before {
    border-color: yellow;
}
.borrow_breadcrumbs .breadcrumb > li.acitve:after {
    border-color: yellow;
}